# How can we manually Upgrade on of the Node pools in GKE whose instance group have custom metadata script

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, upgrade, gcloud

I have a cluster with 3 node pools.How do I upgrade the nodepools , this nodepools instance group template is having some script in custom metadata.

Comment: From google console, can't you just upgrade a given nodepool to a new version (assuming masters are there already)? Actually, this should already be a default, unless you configured it otherwise. What's the issue you're facing? Please check docs: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrading-nodes

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by  @SYN By default, a cluster's nodes have auto-upgrade enabled.

You can manually upgrade a node pool version to match the version of the control plane or to a previous version that is still available and is compatible with the control plane.

You can manually upgrade your node pools to a version compatible with the control plane, using the Google Cloud console or the Google Cloud CLI.

To upgrade a node pool using Cloud console, perform the following steps:

1. Go to the **Google Kubernetes Engine** page in the Cloud console.
2. Next to the cluster you want to edit, click more_vert Actions, then click edit.
3. On the **Cluster details** page, click the Nodes tab.
4. In the **Node Pools** section, click the name of the node pool that you want to upgrade.
5. Click on Edit.
6. Click Change under **Node version**.
7. Select the desired version from the **Node version** drop-down list, then click **Change**.

Refer the document on [Manually upgrading a cluster or a node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#console_1) for more information.